# Double diacritic

Tags: unicode, greek, letters

I am composing with XeLaTeX (no teubner package...) and I need to use on the same letter the diacritic for long, brevis and the accent. I tried as follows but the character that directly follows (α) disappears in the pdf... How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

How it appears:

[image]

It should have the α under the two diacritics, not the ρ...

My code:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = Prosodia.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
    \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
    \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,english,german,russian,serbian}
        \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}



\begin{document}

ἀκηρ\'\uατου

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\'{\u{α}}`, but Linux Libertine doesn't correctly place the combining acute. Other fonts do.

Comment: also never ignore error messages, you get `! Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: @egreg do you have any suggestion? Times creates a lot of problem in my text, I've just seen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax should be `ἀκηρ\'{\u{α}}του`. However, with Linux Libertine we get

[image]

so the combining acute is not placed correctly. With another font it might work better. I tried Old Standard and got

[image]

You might want to define, for this particular font, a specialized accent-making command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Old Standard}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,english,german,russian,serbian}
\setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}

\newrobustcmd{\ba}[1]{% breve-acute
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \char"00B4\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1.3ex}
      \u{#1}\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{ἀκηρ\'{\u{α}}του}

ἀκηρ\ba{α}του

\end{document}
```

I left the Old Standard version for comparison. Remove the declaration of `\greekfont` for your version. However, confining texts in languages different from the main one in their own environment should be best anyway.

[image]

Comment: with lualatex and node renderer libertine looks ok too, with harfbuzz it is wrong.

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But the accents are moved far right.