# Select Theta shape in Greek with Libertine and pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, greek, libertine

Good evening!

Very very simple question I fear. I am using pdflatex to compose a file and I must use the font libertine. Since I have to write a lot in Greek, I would like to get this theta θ in the output instead of this ϑ.

I actually write θ, not ϑ!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek.polutoniko]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{θεόλογος}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One simple option would be to use the `libertinus` package instead, which uses the regular theta. It's a version of Linux Libertine with a math font as well.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear @Giacomo, don't forget to **accept** the answer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png). As of now, **two thirds** of your questions on TeX.SE have been **answered to your satisfaction** (you commented "Thanks, it's perfect"). But you have **accepted none** of them (0%). This is a problem by the standards of TeX.SE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7582/, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/. Having a green-checkmarked answer can help *many future users* in their quest, letting them know at a glance where to look for a good solution or approach to their problem.

Comment: Out of respect to users like Alan, who got out of their way time and again to solve your problems, and to future users (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5235), do make the **small effort** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) to accept the relevant questions. E.g.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568992/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571600/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681704/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628853/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633674/, and of course this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572889/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the `libertinus` version of the Libertine fonts. This version has the regular theta:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek.polutoniko]{babel}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{θεόλογος}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]