# Reledmac - Extra space when using options nonum / nosep in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indentation, reledmac

I would like to solve the following problem with reledmac. In my critical edition (poetry), I have to include some readings for the titles, too. Since these titles are not lines of the poems, they are not numbered. So, I devised the following solution (here with a mock poem):

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = Example.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

%Critical edition
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\Xarrangement[A,B,C]{paragraph}
\Xbeforenotes[A,B,C]{2em plus.4em minus.4em} 
\Xafternote[A,B,C]{2em plus.4em minus.4em} 
\Xnotenumfont{\bfseries}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A,B,C]
\Xnumberonlyfirstintwolines[A,B,C]
\Xlemmaseparator[A,B,C]{]}
\Xbeforelemmaseparator[A,B,C]{0.1em}
\Xafterrule[A,B,C]{1em}
\setmsdataposition{regular-msdata}
\setmsdataseries{A,B,C}
\Xstanza[A,B,C]
\Xstanzaseparator[A,B,C]{.}


\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\numberstanzatrue

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

\stanza
\skipnumbering \textbf{\edtext{Lorem}{\lemma{9 tit. {\normalfont lorem}}\Cfootnote[nonum]{lorem B, lores C}} ipsum}& 
\edtext{dolor}{\Bfootnote{dolos M}} sit \edtext{amet}{\Afootnote{amat L}},& 
consectetur adipiscing elit. \&

\numberstanzafalse
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

However, while removing the number, `nonum` and `nosep` do not avoid the space: therefore, these notes are not in line with the ones that are not marked by `nonum` and `nosep`, as you can see in my mock test:

[image: Problem]

How can I solve/override this problem? Thank you!

Comment: P.S.: I put \& at the end of the poem, but it does not appear here my question, sorry!

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an option for that.
From the manual, §6.2.2.:

> - `nonum` disables line numbering for this note. A horizontal blank space is added instead. You can use `\Xinplaceofnumber` to set it (7.4.15 p. 49).
> - `nosep` to disable the lemma separator for this note. A horizontal blank space is added instead. You can use `\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator` to set it (7.5.1 p. 51).

The default value of `\Xinplaceofnumber` is 1em, which causes the undesired indentation. Set it to zero to suppress the extra space: `\Xinplaceofnumber{0pt}`.

`\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator` is also 1em by default, which is probably fine; your issue stems from `nonum`, not `nosep` anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Solved!

Comment: @Giacomo: Glad it helped! Please remember to accept the answer (green checkmark) then!