# Reledpar: setcounter, Roman/Arabic numbers in Stanza, R in verse numbering

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I am using for the first time the package reledpar, and I have some trouble with some features that I would like to have in my edition, namely:

1. Some stanzas in my edition should be numerated with Roman number, some other with Arabic number. Before, I used renewcommand to obtain this output, but the command does not work anymore with relepar. Any clue?
2. I have to restart the numbering of stanzas, but \setcounter{stanza}{0} does not work when I use reledpar. Any clue?
3. I would like not to have the letter "R" after the number of verse on the right page. I think it's rather easy, but I could not find the way in the reledpar package.

An example follows:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = Example.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
    
    
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
    \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
    \setotherlanguages{latin,greek}
        \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}
        \setkeys{latin}{variant=modern}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}



\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}

{
\renewcommand{\thestanza}{%
    \textbf{\Roman{stanza}}%
    }

\setcounter{stanza}{0}
\beginnumbering
\numberstanzatrue

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

\stanza
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&
consectetur adipiscing elit&
Morbi ultricies nulla vel turpis maximus, vitae sollicitudin metus efficitur&
Morbi vel enim dolor.&
Vivamus quis accumsan augue.\&

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\stanza[\vspace{1mm}]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&
consectetur adipiscing elit&
Morbi ultricies nulla vel turpis maximus, vitae sollicitudin metus efficitur&
Morbi vel enim dolor.&
Vivamus quis accumsan augue.\&

\numberstanzafalse
\endnumbering
}
\end{Leftside}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{Rightside}

{
\renewcommand{\thestanza}{%
    \textbf{\Roman{stanza}}%
    }
    
\beginnumbering
\numberstanzatrue

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

\stanza
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&
consectetur adipiscing elit&
Morbi ultricies nulla vel turpis maximus, vitae sollicitudin metus efficitur&
Morbi vel enim dolor.&
Vivamus quis accumsan augue.\&
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\stanza[\vspace{1mm}]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&
consectetur adipiscing elit&
Morbi ultricies nulla vel turpis maximus, vitae sollicitudin metus efficitur&
Morbi vel enim dolor.&
Vivamus quis accumsan augue.\&

\numberstanzafalse
\endnumbering
}
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\newpage



%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}

{
\renewcommand{\thestanza}{%
    \textbf{\arabic{stanza}}%
    }

\setcounter{stanza}{0}
\beginnumbering
\numberstanzatrue

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

\stanza
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&
consectetur adipiscing elit&
Morbi ultricies nulla vel turpis maximus, vitae sollicitudin metus efficitur&
Morbi vel enim dolor.&
Vivamus quis accumsan augue.\&

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\stanza[\vspace{1mm}]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&
consectetur adipiscing elit&
Morbi ultricies nulla vel turpis maximus, vitae sollicitudin metus efficitur&
Morbi vel enim dolor.&
Vivamus quis accumsan augue.\&

\numberstanzafalse
\endnumbering
}
\end{Leftside}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{Rightside}

{
\renewcommand{\thestanza}{%
    \textbf{\arabic{stanza}}%
    }
    
\setcounter{stanza}{0}
\beginnumbering
\numberstanzatrue

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

\stanza
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&
consectetur adipiscing elit&
Morbi ultricies nulla vel turpis maximus, vitae sollicitudin metus efficitur&
Morbi vel enim dolor.&
Vivamus quis accumsan augue.\&

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\stanza[\vspace{1mm}]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&
consectetur adipiscing elit&
Morbi ultricies nulla vel turpis maximus, vitae sollicitudin metus efficitur&
Morbi vel enim dolor.&
Vivamus quis accumsan augue.\&

\numberstanzafalse
\endnumbering
}
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [reledpar manual](https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledpar.pdf).

(1) and (2): The manual explains that `reledpar` differentiates the counter `stanza` into two counters, one for the right side, one for the left. Same with the correspondent formatting command `\thestanza` (p. 23).

> When using `\stanzanumtrue` (9.10 p. 62) in parallel typesetting, stanza counter is replaced by `stanzaL` counter in left side and by `stanzaR` counter in right side. Consequently, you can redefine `\thestanzaL` and `\thestanzaR` to change their aspect.

(3): `reledpar` introduces a "line flag" that is automatically appended to the right side numbering. This can be redefined at will or suppressed altogether (7.7., p. 21).

> **7.7 Line flag**
>
> A “R” is appended to the line numbers of the right texts. This may be useful for parallel columns but for parallel pages it might be more appropriate to redefine it using `\setRlineflag{⟨flag⟩}`. Use `\setRlineflag{}` to empty it.

The packages `reledmac` and `reledpar` stand out in the LaTeX world for their excellent and detailed documentation – do use it, it will usually answer your questions!

Comment: Thank you very much, Marquinho: you are completely right. The package documentation solved me my issues but one: when I wasn't using reledpar, I used Xstanza and Xstanzaseparator to print stanza numbers (e.g. 9.2) in notes. Now they do not appear: I tried stanzaL/stanzaR [error] and also the following newcommand from doc. ["already defined"]. Do you know the solution or how to find it in doc.? 

\newcommand{\printstanza}[0]{%
\ifboolexpr{bool{l@dpairing} or bool{l@dprintingpages} or bool{l@dprintingcolumns}}{%
\ifledRcol@%
\thestanzaR%
\else%
\thestanzaL%
\fi%
}{%
\thestanza%
}%
}

Comment: please open a github issue with an MWE example explained your error. It may be a bug.

Comment: @Giacomo: you're welcome! Sidenote: to open a github issue, see https://github.com/maieul/ledmac#debug-and-feature-requests. And please remember *accepting* the answer if it solved your problem (with this as with other questions).

Comment: Issue open: https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/934