# Reledpar: Print stanza numbering

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I have a issue with reledpar. I want the number of the stanzas to appear together with the number of lines in all my critical apparatus: before using reledpar, the commands \Xstanza and \Xstanzaseparator worked, but now they do not produce any output.

I believe it depends on stanzaL and stanzaR. In reledmac package (p. 351-352), it seems that the way to solve this issue is the following newcommand:

```
\newcommand{\printstanza}[0]{%
\ifboolexpr{bool{l@dpairing} or bool{l@dprintingpages} or bool{l@dprintingcolumns}}{%
\ifledRcol@%
\thestanzaR%
\else%
\thestanzaL%
\fi%
}{%
\thestanza%
}%
}
```

However, if I add it, the following error appears: "Command \printstanza already defined or name \end... illegal, see p. 192 of the manual". Furthermore, in this command I cannot understand how to add information as through \Xstanzaseparator.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The maintainer thinks this might, in fact, be a bug, and has [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633674/) to open an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac#debug-and-feature-requests)

Comment: Also, remember that the portion of the manual you are quoting *describes the implementation* of the package, meaning, the definition has already come into effect as you load it. Hence the error message "Control sequence already defined". Have you tried `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\printstanza} ... \makeatother`? And to what effect?

Comment: It was not a bug, but a misunderstood of the handbook https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/934#issuecomment-1038291190.