# Stanza – Customize number for a single stanza (reledmac, reledpar)

Tags: numbering, reledmac, reledpar

Dear all sorry for bothering.

I have a question related to `stanza`/`astanza` numbering. Please note that for the .tex I have to compile, I cannot use the package verse.

For a single stanza, I need change the numbering from the normal arabic to arabic+roman (e.g., 1 --> 1 I). I thought to use `\numberstanzafalse` and to substitute the number of the stanza with `\ledinnernote` or `\ledleftnote`, but by using these two commands: 1. the note is closer to the main text as the normal stanza numbering; 2. the font and its size are different; 3. somehow they generate strange font forms (see the screenshot). In reledmac and reledpar manuals, this issue is not dealt with.

Any clue? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside} 
\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\numberstanzatrue
\setcounter{stanzaL}{47}
\begin{astanza}
Line& 
Line&
Line&
Line\&
\end{astanza}
\setcounter{stanzaL}{48}
\numberstanzatrue
\begin{astanza}
Line& 
Line&
Line&
Line\&
\end{astanza}
\numberstanzafalse
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

%---------

\begin{Rightside} 
\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\numberstanzafalse
\begin{astanza}
\ledinnernote{\textbf{48 I}}%
Line& %here (and only here) the number should be 1 I instead of 1
Line& 
Line&
Line&
Line\&
\end{astanza}
\setcounter{stanzaR}{48}
\numberstanzatrue
\begin{astanza}
Line& 
Line&
Line&
Line\&
\end{astanza}
\numberstanzafalse
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your code to remove all the unnecessary "noise" (no disrespect to Sappho!) and show clearly where the issue lies, in compliance with the requirements of this site. Please submit a MWE (stress on **minimal**) next time.

Comment: Dear @Giacomo, don't forget to **accept** the answer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png). As of now, **two thirds** of your questions on TeX.SE have been **answered to your satisfaction** (you commented "Thanks, it's perfect"). But you have **accepted none** of them (0%). This is a problem by the standards of TeX.SE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7582/, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/. Having a green-checkmarked answer can help *many future users* in their quest, since they know at a glance where to look for a good solution or good approach to their problem.

Comment: Out of respect to users like me, who got out of their way time and again to solve your problems, and to future users (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5235), do make the **small effort** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) to accept the relevant questions. E.g.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568992/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571600/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572889/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628853/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633674/, and of course this very question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681704/.

Comment: @marquinho done! I'm very sorry I was not quick in accepting your answers

Comment: Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do not use a patchwork* of "stanza numbering here, sidenotes there", do not waste time in unnecessary manual adjustment.
**Instead, have the stanza numbering work for you.**

Did you look at the [manual, sect. 9.10](https://ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledmac.pdf#page=57)? `reledmac` allows you to customize the display format of stanza numbers by redefining the commands `\thestanza` and friends. That is, in the same way you'd *customize the look of other `LaTeX` counter representations* (`\thepage`, `\thechapter`...).

If you want to append optional text to the automatically generated representation of the counters `stanza`, `stanzaL` or `stanzaR`, add a placeholder to the definitions of `\thestanza` and friends:

```
\newcommand{\mysubcounter}{}
\renewcommand{\thestanza}{\textbf{\arabic{stanza}\mysubcounter}}
\renewcommand{\thestanzaL}{\textbf{\arabic{stanzaL}\mysubcounter}}
\renewcommand{\thestanzaR}{\textbf{\arabic{stanzaR}\mysubcounter}}
```

Then you can specify the realization of `\mysubcounter` on a case-by-case basis:

```
\renewcommand{\mysubcounter}{~I}   % gives you "48~I"
\renewcommand{\mysubcounter}{~II}  % gives you "48~II"
\renewcommand{\mysubcounter}{}     % "resets" and gives "48"
```

Applying this to your case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\numberstanzatrue

\newcommand{\mysubcounter}{}
\renewcommand{\thestanzaL}{\textbf{\arabic{stanzaL}\mysubcounter}}
\renewcommand{\thestanzaR}{\textbf{\arabic{stanzaR}\mysubcounter}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside} 
\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
%
\begin{astanza}
Line& 
Line&
Line&
Line\&
\end{astanza}
%
\begin{astanza}
Line& 
Line&
Line&
Line\&
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

%---------

\begin{Rightside} 
\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
%
\renewcommand{\mysubcounter}{~I}%
\begin{astanza}
Line& %here (and only here) the number should be 1 I instead of 1
Line&
Line&
Line\&
\end{astanza}
%
\renewcommand{\mysubcounter}{}
\begin{astanza}
Line& 
Line&
Line&
Line\&
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

[image: Custom stanza numbering with an appended "I"]

Comment: Many thanks, @marquinho!

Comment: @Giacomo: Great! If this helped, don't forget to (upvote and) mark the answer as accepted!